# export a random forest model to C code for use outside of mlr3

Tags: mlr3

I have trained a radom forest model like this:

task <- as_task_regr(my_data, id= "rf", target = "Q")

train_set = sample(task$row_ids, 0.80 * task$nrow)
test_set = setdiff(task$row_ids, train_set)

learner_rf <- lrn("regr.ranger", num.trees= 30)
learner_rf$train(task, row_ids = train_set)

I'm happy with the model and want to export it to C code for use in other simulations like

Q = Random_forest(V1,V2,...)

d/dt = periph * Q/V2 - centr * (CL/V1 + Q/V1)

How can I do this? Are there mlr3 functions that I can use?

I didn't find similar questions from internet.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by `mlr3` or the underlying package as far as I know.

Comment: While I was not able to get the c-code from a random forest, I did get the c-code from the 'Cubist' package, which essentially generates a random forest, but with linear regression model on the terminal nodes. The mlr3 output learner_cubist$model$splits contain the rules, and the learner_cubist$model$coefficients contain the  linear models, which are quite conveinent for export. I'm now wondering how I can use a lasso to get an efficient set of rules.